# como hacer un while con acumulador en sql server

Tags: sql-server, while

hola soy nuevo con esto de sql y me gustaria hacer un bucle que por medio de un acumludor me imprima los resultados del while en la misma fila
**ejempo de lo que obtengo**
|dato |
|-----|
|hola |
|mundo|
|sql  |
**ejemplo de lo que quiero**
hola mundo sql

```
create table registro (id int identity (1,1), dato varchar (25))
insert into registro (dato)
values ( 'hola')
insert into registro (dato)
values ('mundo' )
insert into registro (dato)
values ('sql')

declare @numDatos int, @contador int=1;
declare @acumulador varchar (100)
set @numDatos= (select COUNT(*) from registro)
select @numDatos 


while (@contador<=@numDatos)
begin

set @acumulador=( select dato from registro where id=@contador)
print @acumulador 
set @contador=@contador+1 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede usar el `while` para concatenar los resultados en `@acumulador` e imprimir el valor al finalizar las iteraciones:

```
while (@contador<=@numDatos)
    begin
    set @acumulador = CONCAT(@acumulador, ' ', ( select dato from registro where id=@contador))
    set @contador=@contador+1 
    end
    
print @acumulador
```

Comment: muchas gracias, si resolvio mi problema